# Webpack equivalent of Vite import with '?url'

Tags: webpack, vite, webassembly

We have a repo that is built using vite and includes a line

```
import abcUrl from "@tt/shared/assets/abc.wasm?url";
```

If I log that I see `/@fs/...` which is shorthand for something else I guess.

I need to implement the same wasm code in another project that uses webpack. In my webpack.config.js I have set

```
    experiments: {
        asyncWebAssembly: true,
        syncWebAssembly: true,
    },
```

but no explict loaders. (I also tried other permutationsof these booleans). But the error I get is `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'env' in '/..../shared/assets/abc'`